# Would FB deprecate the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication method for its Chat API

Tags: facebook-chat, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Today, Facebook announces its Graph API v2.0 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog. One permission xmpp_login is no longer available in the new version according to the change log. This permission is critical in order to generate an access token which can be used to authenticate a FB chat client via X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism, this is clearly described  at FB Chat API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat.  Any FB App created after 30 April is forced to use v2.0 API, hence cannot request user on xmpp_login permission. Although the old app still has one year time to upgrade, I didn't find any info how to mitigate this missing. Is that meaning FB will deprecate the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL for its Chat API?

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat have been update now. And yes it is deprecated.

Comment: looks Facebook deprecated the entire chat api. This is surprising me.   FB doesn't mention any alternative. This is interesting..., an impact from acquisition of Whatsapp?

Comment: On the dev site `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat` it says `Once version 1.0 is deprecated, chat.facebook.com will no longer be available.` Does it mean facebook chat will be dead or just the domain chat.facebook.com will be dead?

Comment: It means that the chat API will be dead.